# System periodically stalls for less then 1s then resumes normally

Tags: 13.04, performance

Periodically my system stalls for a short while (less then 1s). When it occurs, the mouse pointer hangs or stutters and my keyboard input doesn't show up on the screen. After it's done, the keyboard input appears instantly and my mouse jumps to the point where it should be.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on a MacBook Air. I turned the swappiness down to 10, also looked at vmstat (to check if it's swapping) and looked at dmesg and syslog, aswell as top. I can't find any aberrant behavior, there are no logmessages and no swapping.

My system is entirely up-to-date.

```
$ uname -a
Linux wega 3.8.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 14 22:16:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The following output was captured with iostat -xm 1 at the time of one of the stalls:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10,08    0,00    3,27    0,25    0,00   86,40

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00    13,00    0,00    2,00     0,00     0,06    60,00     0,01    4,00    0,00    4,00   4,00   0,80
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
```

There is some io, but I'm not entirely convinced that this is the problem, especially since it's just a couple of write reqs. When I run bonnie++ it gets good results on writes, and the frequency of the stalls doesn't appear to increase.

I ran bonnie++ before on /tmp which performed very well, now I'm running it on my encrypted homedir and it's not doing so goed at all, it's running at 99% CPU usage, but with almost 0 disk util (as shown by iostat).

Comment: Does the kernel produce any messages (`dmesg`) around the time this happens? And how about your general system log (`/var/log/syslog`)?

Comment: Checked both, no log messages when it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with building a kernel from source, there are some options in the kernel config, which may affect latency and apparent responsiveness in the running machine.

For instance, in the build configuration for the kernel on my laptop, I use:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
```

That seems to result in suitable responsiveness, for desktop use.

Of course, the reader unfamiliar with kernel building might want to consult some documentation about the process. There appear to be a number of "Howto" type documents about building a custom kernel on Ubuntu. [Here's a straightforward one featuring *make menuconfig*](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-kernel/). Granted, it doesn't mention the *linux-tools* package and related packages, but it does get to the point of how to build a kernel from source.

Here's a [more expansive tutorial, featuring a direct pull from the Kernel's Git repository.](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/compile-mainline-kernel-ubuntu/) GIYF. HTH. Cheers.

Comment: Building a new kernel is absolutely no problem at all. Going to give it a try tonight when I get home, can't afford to break my laptop on the job ;).

Comment: Well, I finally got around to compiling a fresh kernel, 3.8.11, I've set the flags you suggest but it doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the stalls are linked to disk activity ?

Ubuntu Desktop ships with mlocate enabled, which "scan" the drive once per day and generate quite an amount of reads.
On my desktop, it often leads to stalls like yours. Disabling mlocate in /etc/cron.daily solved it for me (`sudo mv /etc/cron.daily/mlocate /etc/cron.daily/mlocate.disabled`)

Comment: I have amended my original question with iostat output at the moment of one of the stalls.

Comment: IMHO, it looks like the system is doing some burst of disk access, which is shown by the iowait status. But as the average value is rather slow, it's difficult to pinpoint the cause. Maybe you can "fix it" by trying a different io scheduler (deadline shows good performance for legacy drives, noop for SSD)

Comment: It's set to deadline at the moment, but I tried CFQ, does not help at all, going to give noop a try, since it's an SSD. I also ran bonnie++ on my encrypted home partition, which shows horrible performance, but on /tmp it runs very well.

Comment: When I dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M in my homedir, I get around 30mb/s write performance, in /tmp I get more then 300mb/s. Seems the encryption is causing the problem.

Comment: It's very possible that the encryption is causing some stalls while flushing buffers. Maybe you can fiddle with buffer settings by putting some lines in `/etc/rc.local`:  
`echo 50 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio  
echo 50 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio  
echo 6000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs  
echo 6000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs`

Comment: I could try fiddling with those, but I didn't really expect a 10x performance hit from the disk encryption.

Comment: No, but if you can avoid the skips, it should leads to a better user experience...

Comment: That is true, I made the adjustments and I'll try to fiddle around some more, but I'd really would like to solve the problem.

Comment: I disabled the homedir encryption, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Which filesystem type are you using on your home partition ? I don't know if by default ext4 mounts are using the discard option by default but it can explain some latency.

Comment: This is the mount line of the partition with my homedir: /dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro).